# Conditional posteriors - Is this the correct way to obtain them?

Tags: bayesian

Forgive the novice question but I'm new to Bayesian inference...

Suppose $y \sim p(y|\mu, \sigma, \theta)$ and we want to sample from the posterior using Gibbs sampling. That is, we need the conditional posteriors of the form $p(\mu | y, \sigma, \theta)$ etc (for simplicity I will denote all distributions by $p$ though I know this is incorrect/poor notation)

We have the likelihood which is

$$L(y| \mu, \sigma, \theta) = p(y | \mu, \sigma, \theta)$$

and suppose we also have the priors such as $p (\mu)$. Am I correct to say that the conditional posterior of, say, $\mu$ is obtained by (assuming independent priors):

$p(\mu | y,\sigma,\theta) = \frac{p(\mu ,y,\sigma,\theta)}{p(y,\sigma,\theta)}= \frac{p(y | \mu,\sigma,\theta)p(\mu,\sigma,\theta)}{p(y,\sigma,\theta)} =\frac{p(y | \mu,\sigma,\theta)p(\mu)p(\sigma,\theta)}{p(y,\sigma,\theta)}  \propto  p(y | \mu,\sigma,\theta)p(\mu)$

Hence if $\mu$ has conjugate prior, we need only consider the likelihood and prior of $\mu$?

Comment: This is only correct if $\mu$ is independent a priori from $\sigma$ and $\theta$.